# TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.ref is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to set the path for uploading the image but unfortunately stuck with this error:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import projectStorage from 'firebase';
```

useStorage() Function is for handlig file upload and returning some useful value about
that upload like :

1. upload Progress
2. any errors
3. image url

   ```
   const useStorage = (data) => {

    // states for storing data 

    // 1. state responsible for storing progress of file which we upload  
    const [progress,setProgress] = useState(0);
    //2. state responsible for storing any errors while uploading
    const [error,setError] = useState(null);
    //3. state responsible for storing image url comming back from server
    const [url,setUrl] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() => {

        // 1. get a reference(path)  where a file should be save

        const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(data.name); //path at which file will be uploaded

       storageRef.put(data);


    }, [data])


        return {progress ,error , url } 
    }

    export default useStorage;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use storage?

```
let filename = 'test'
const reference = storage().ref(filename);
try {
  await reference.putFile(photo).then(async () => {
    const url = await reference.getDownloadURL();
    setUrl(url);
  });
} catch (error) {console.error(error)}
```